# Simplifying NLog JSON Log Messages Sent to Elasticsearch and Kibana in .NET 6.0 Web API

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, kibana, nlog

I'm currently working with NLog in my .NET 6.0 Web API project. I have set up NLog to map my logs to Elasticsearch and Kibana. However, I've encountered an issue where each log message includes all the log attributes every time.

Here is an example of what I'm currently seeing:

```
{
  "_index": "nlog-2023.07.06",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "_KQ5KYkBCGb3ABnk7OKt",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2023-07-06T03:23:29.3236253+00:00",
    "level": "Info",
    "message": "{ \"timestamp\": \"2023-07-06 03:23:29.3236\", \"level\": \"Info\", \"logger\": \"GuardianBackend.Controllers.WeatherForecastController\", \"message\": \"APP INFO: Generated 5 forecasts.\", \"machineName\": \"4f549e581aa0\", \"processId\": \"2638\", \"threadId\": \"7\" }"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2023-07-06T03:23:29.323Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1688613809323
  ]
}
```

However, what I want is a simplified message structure like this:

```
{
  "_index": "nlog-2023.07.06",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "_KQ5KYkBCGb3ABnk7OKt",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2023-07-06T03:23:29.3236253+00:00",
    "level": "Info",
    "message": "APP INFO: Generated 5 forecasts."
  }
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2023-07-06T03:23:29.323Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1688613809323
  ]
}
```

I've tried to resolve this issue by modifying my NLog configuration file and the related coding sections, but I haven't had any luck. Could anyone point out where I might be going wrong?

Here is my current NLog configuration file:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Error"
      internalLogFile="internal-nlog.txt">

    <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
        <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
    </extensions>

    <!-- define a common layout -->
    <variable name="commonLayout" value="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${custom-message}" />

    <!-- the targets to write to -->
    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="nlog-all-${shortdate}.log" layout="${commonLayout}" />

        <target xsi:type="Console" name="allconsole" layout="${commonLayout}" />

        <target name="elastic" xsi:type="ElasticSearch" uri="http://elasticsearch:9200" index="nlog-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}" includeAllProperties="false">
            <layout type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">
                <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${longdate}" />
                <attribute name="level" layout="${level}" />
                <attribute name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
                <attribute name="message" layout="${message:raw=true}" />
                <attribute name="machineName" layout="${machinename}" />
                <attribute name="processId" layout="${processid}" />
                <attribute name="threadId" layout="${threadid}" />
                <attribute name="exception" layout="${exception:format=ToString}" />
            </layout>
        </target>
    </targets>

    <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
    <rules>
        <!-- Exclude Microsoft's 'Info' logs -->
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="allfile,allconsole,elastic" final="true" />

        <!-- General rule -->
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="allfile,allconsole,elastic" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Here is my Program.cs:

```
// NLog configuration
builder.Logging.AddNLog();
```

And here is the part where I call the logs:
`_logger.LogInformation($"APP INFO: Generated {forecasts.Length} forecasts.");`

Comment: Maybe replace the use of `<layout type="JsonLayout"` with `<layout type="SimpleLayout" text="${message:withException=true}" />`

Comment: @RolfKristensen Great, now the items inside the message are organized in JSON format. But the duplication continues, the message appears twice.

Comment: I cannot guess where you are seeing duplicate messages.